# how to make a newline in a String

Tags: haskell

```
f :: [Int] -> String 
f [] = "a\nb"
```

this is return

> a\nb

so the \n is not working , It work with putStrLn but it is an IO () and not a String, any way to make a newline in String

Comment: It is, but you need to use `putStrLn` to *print* the *content* of the string.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between the *content* of a string, and its representation. `ghci` will show the *representation* of the string. This means it wraps the content between double quotes, and escapes special characters.

If you thus call `f []`, it will print `"a\nb"` in the interpreter, which is the *representation* of the string. But in the *content* of the string, it contains a new line character.

You use [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) to *print* the *content* of the string.

Comment: yes I know but I must change the function to f :: [Int] -> IO () , so there is no way to return a string and not a IO ?

Comment: because I want use the output in another String function

Comment: @anasstahiri: but as said before, the string *contains* a new line. You can use it in another function. It is only the interpret that shows it as a string *literal*, and not the content of the string. That is not that strange, In the Python and csharp interpreter, it is exaclty the same for example.